# Log to a single file in IIS6 (as with IIS7)

Tags: logging, iis-6

IIS7 allows me to configure the server so that all sites log to a single file. This is extremely convenient because i can do all of my analysis in one place.

I can not figure out how to do the same on the IIS6 side.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

Bacon,
Sorry, this is not possible in IIS6.
-Chris